Creating a text file in Python consisting of employee records on number of hours worked in each day of the week, ID, Fisrt & second name role
using Python to generate a text file. There should be four employees in the text file, each of the roles of manager or barista. Every worker should have a distinct ID that indicates how many hours they have put in each day of the week. It is also necessary to keep track of the overtime worked on weekdays and weekends.
I tried making the text file in Python but could not be able to create organize the data well according to the employee ID, First Name, Second Name, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun.

Please show what you've tried and someone may be able to help you
